# PostgreSQL, lo_export query to stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, delphi, stored-procedures, plpgsql, psql

I am working on a Delphi 7 application that uses PostgreSQL 9.0. I have some images stored in the database as `OID` and the application connects to the PostgreSQL remotely.

I'm using this query:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d MyDB -U myDB_admin -c  "\lo_export 16848379 'C://leeImage.jpeg'"
```

and display the image on the form. This works fine but takes about 1 second or so to execute and display the image.

So I was trying to convert the query to a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_FISHIMAGE(path TEXT ,Host TEXT,DatabaseName TEXT,userName TEXT,outputpath TEXT) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  //perform this..!!!
  //"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U myDB_admin -c  "\lo_export 16848379 'C://leeImage.jpeg'"

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've searched on the Internet but cannot figure out if the conversion is even possible.
Can anyone tell me how to convert the above query to a stored procedure?

Comment: i cant add `psql` Tag somehow

Comment: If those pictures aren't *really* big, then using `bytea` is probably a better approach

Comment: Can you update your post with the name/version of your Delphi PostgreSQL driver? Each driver has its own way to fetch large objects and binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching an external program from a server function written in `plpgsql` is not possible, and even if switching to a language that supports it, like `plperlu`, that wouldn't solve the problem, because:

- it would perform as poorly as when doing it from a client machine, since the overhead of launching psql and establishing a connection would be the same.
- the `\lo_export` command would create the file on the database server, whereas you need it on the client machine. Otherwise you could call the [lo_export()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-funcs.html) SQL function, and launching `psql` just to retrieve an image wouldn't be necessary in the first place.

The simple, architecturally clean solution to the problem would be to use the BLOB API that the Delphi database driver probably exposes to transfer binary data from server to client.

In the unlikely event that's there nothing at all in the API to fetch binary data, it'd still be possible to cook a server-side function encoding a binary large object to a text-encoded version with `base64` or similar, and decode it client-side. That would still be way more efficient that launching psql each time a picture needs to be retrieved.